# Pulling settings from MySQL using Object-Orientated PHP

Tags: php, mysql, object

Ok, so I am slowly migrating from Procedural to OOP, and I'm finding it all pretty straight forward apart from one thing.

I used to use this method for pulling my settings data from a simple two-column settings table comprising of a row for each setting, defined with 'setting' and 'value' fields:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `settings`");
while ($current_setting = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $setting[$current_setting['setting']] = $current_setting['value'];
}
```

As you can see, I manipulated it so that I could simply use $setting['any_setting_name'] to display the corresponding 'value' within that setting's row.  I'm not sure if this is a silly way of doing things but no matter, I'm moving on anyway..

However, since moving to object orientated PHP, I don't really know how to do something similar..

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `settings`");
while ($current_setting = $query->fetch_object()) {
    echo $current_setting->setting; // echo's each setting name
    echo $current_setting->value; // echo's each setting value
}
```

As you can see, I'm perfectly able to retrieve the data, but what I want is to be able to use it later on in the form of: `$setting->setting_name;` which will echo the VALUE from the row where `setting` is equal to 'setting_name'..

So basically if I have a row in my settings table where `setting` is 'site_url' and `value` is 'http://example.com/', I want $setting->site_url; to contain 'http://example.com/'.. Or something to the same effect..

Can anyone help me out here? I'm at a brick-wall right now.. Probably something really stupid I'm overlooking..

Comment: Thanks Prix :) I've come to realise that since posting this, but still don't know exactly how I'd do it, currently I can still only append the setting name to $setting->setting and the setting value to $setting->value, I still can't achieve $setting->setting_name = the value :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working with a resource it has a pointer.  Once you get to the end you can't use it anymore.  I think you can reset it but why not mix the new with the old?

I don't think you're going to have too much overhead, any that matters anyway, to do something like this:

```php
$settings = array();
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `settings`");
while ($current_setting = $query->fetch_object()) {
     $settings[$current_setting->setting] = $current_setting->value;
}
```

Now you can use `$settings` as much as you want.

**UPDATE**

Haven't tested this or used it but are you looking to do something like this?  Consider the following pseudo code and may not actually work.

```php
$settings = new stdClass();
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `settings`");
while ($current_setting = $query->fetch_object()) {
     $settings->{$current_setting->setting} = $current_setting->value;
}
```

Comment: Though I have a feeling you're looking at trying to store objects within objects.

Comment: I had considered mixing them in such a way but I was generally trying to avoid the use of $settings['site_url'] and move toward $settings->site_url purely for the sake of consistency.. Any idea how I could manipulate a class to achieve the desired result?

Comment: EDIT: Should've refreshed first I guess :P I will try out the second part, but failing that the first part will do - I'm overthinking things as usual :P

Comment: @Chuckun I have done the same my friend.  Just because you are moving towards OOP, doesn't mean you cannot use arrays anymore and try to stuff everything into an object.  Everything has it's place.  It's tough at times to know which to use.  I've been there!

Comment: @Chuckun I just expaned my answer for a possible object solution.

Comment: OK, your second code with a little tweak `$settings->{$current_setting->setting}` (instead of value), actually works :) I am however getting an error for creating a default object from an empty value, which I'm kind of baffled by since the variable $settings has been defined correctly but I'll figure that out :) Thank you!

Comment: Just noticed that.  Changed.

Comment: OK the error was due to my own mistake - your final code snippet works perfectly :) Thank you sir!